# How to output file name with extension by a Windows batch script?

Tags: batch-file

I have the following .bat script:

```
FOR /f "skip=1" %%x IN ('wmic os get localdatetime') DO IF NOT DEFINED MyDate SET MyDate=%%x
SET today=%MyDate:~0,4%%MyDate:~4,2%%MyDate:~6,2%

SET fileext=".csv"

SET Username=some_user
SET Password=some_password
SET Domain=some_domain

SET LDAPport=3268

SET LDAPAttributeList=sAMAccountName
SET LDAPfilter="(&(objectClass=User)(objectCategory=Person))"

FOR /F "tokens=1,2 delims=|" %%G IN (files_DCs_map.txt) DO (
    csvde -f %%G%today%fileext -r %LDAPfilter% -l %LDAPAttributeList% -t %LDAPport% -s %%H -b %Username% %Domain% %Password% -u
)
```

This script uses the csvde utility to extract data out of a Windows AD domain controller and write it to a file. The file name and domain controller IP is stored in file `files_DCs_map.txt`. A sample line in this file is:

```
some_DC|some_IP
```

The script works, but it is outputting incorrect file names. I want file names in the form `<some_DC><today>.csv`. It is currently outputting file names in the form `<some_DC><today>fileext`. That is, it's not interpreting variable fileext correctly. For example, it outputs file name `some_DC20171128fileext`. I want this file name to be `some_DC20171128.csv` instead. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular variables in batch need to be enclosed in percent signs. You have specified the filename as

```
%%G%today%fileext
```

`%%G` is the loop variable. `%today%` is the date, which works as you expect. `filext`, missing the percents, is just a literal. You need to put it like this:

```
%%G%today%%fileext%
```